# How do I divide a row in sub rows?

Tags: theming

If I want to divide a row into some sub-rows in Drupal 8, what should the code be?

[image]

The following code worked fine for simple tables. I need to do something with the `$rows` array to divide the rows in sub-rows. How can I achieve this?

```
$form['mytable'] = array(
  '#theme'  => 'table',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#rows'   => $rows,
  '#empty'  => t('Not Found.'),
);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Drupal 8:**

```
$table = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => ['ab', 'cd', 'ef'],
  [
    [
      '#plain_text' => 'rowspan',
      '#wrapper_attributes' => ['rowspan' => 2],
    ],
    ['#markup' => '1'],
    ['#markup' => '1'],
  ],
  [['#markup' => '1'], ['#markup' => '1']],
];
```

**Result:**

[image: Table with rowspan]

See [Drupal Documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Table.php/class/Table/8.2.x) for a colspan example

Answer (score 1):

This is still similar to how it was done in Drupal 7 and Drupal 6 with the use of colspan or rowspan attributes. The documentation for [template_preprocess_table](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_table/8.2.x) states

> Each cell can be either a string or an associative array with the
>   following keys:
>
> - data: The string or render array to display in the table cell.
> - header: Indicates this cell is a header.
> - Any HTML attributes, such as "colspan", to apply to the table cell.

So the top row of your example image would be like such:

```
$rows = [
  [
    ['data' => '', 'attributes' => ['rowspan' => 3]],
    '',
    '',
    '',
  ],
  ['', '', ''],
  ['', '', ''],
];
```

in order to get the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="3"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <tD></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```